# Proper regex expression to find string and then match last 2 digits of number after string if the digits equal to 00

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I'm trying to perform a search on a line for a specific word "seed" and then check that the number after the word ends in "00". The line looks like this

```
2022/05/13 17:32:26 10716828 118693c3 [DEBUG Client 8228] Generating level 13 area "1_1_town" with seed 120481576136500
```

I can get the regex for the word and the space after it with `\bseed\b\s`
I can also get the last two digits with a simple `[0][0]$` (since the number is always at the and of the line.).
I can't seem to merge the two so it checks for the word seed and then matches on the "00" (the \d[0][0] doesn't work).

What regex expression do I need to get things working properly ?

I'm reading a log file. The `seed` + number is not always the same number. Here's a larger example of the file:

```
2022/05/13 17:32:26 10716828 118693c3 [DEBUG Client 8228] Generating level 13 area "1_1_town" with seed 3813267107
2022/05/13 17:32:28 10718437 f22b69c1 [INFO Client 8228] Tile hash: 1809335384 2022/05/13 17:32:26 10716828 118693c3 [DEBUG Client 8228] Generating level 13 area "1_1_town" with seed 1204811500
```

I only want to match and pull the last two digits if they are `00` to put in a variable for the larger script. There are other lines in the file where the number also ends in a `00`. I don't want those because they aren't preceded by the keyword seed. I only want to check the number if it is on the same line as seed and the number ends in 00. If I use the regex as it is it will highlight "seed 1204811500". I need to put just the "00" in the script.

```
FilePath := A_ScriptDir "\TestLogFile2.txt" ;relative path to file
File := FileOpen(FilePath, "r")
OldLogFileSize := 0
File.Seek(0, 2)
Loop { 
    LogFileSize := File.Length
    if (LogFileSize > OldLogFileSize) { 
        Loop { 
            if File.AtEOF
                Break
            TextLine := File.Readline()
            If InStr(TextLine, seed) { 
                RegExMatch(TextLine, "\bseed\s+\d*00$", RFNum)
                MsgBox, % "The ID is " RFNum
            }
        }
        OldLogFileSize := LogFileSize
    }
    Sleep, 1000 ; wait one second before checking again (change to whatever) 
}
return Esc:: 
File.Close()
ExitApp
return
```

Comment: If you can specify the regex flavor (BRE, ERE, PCRE etc.) and/or the language you use, you will have matching answers.

Comment: I'm not using a specific flavour. The regex is part of an auto hot key script, so it's basically a batch script, not java, python or any other coding language. That makes it a lot simpler. Barmar's solution almost gets me there but not quite. I need the regex to only pick up the "00"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the number is a fixed number of digits, you can match `00` with a lookbehind that matches `seed` followed by the first 13 digits:

```
(?<=\bseed \d{13})00
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pQwaI6/2)

This won't work if the number can be variable-length, because lookbehinds have to be fixed length.

Comment: This works but it matches the whole string - seed 120481576136500.

Is there a way to make it search but only highlight 00 ? (maybe I'm interpreting the output from regex101 incorrectly but it looks like it finds the whole thing)

Comment: I thought you just wanted to test for a match. Why do you need to return something if it will always be the same `00`?

Comment: I'm reading each entry in a log file as they come in. The example I gave is one line. The log file has other lines. Some of those have seed + a number but that number is not always the same. I need to read each line as it is written to the file and only grab the line where the number ends with a "00" . Here's an example of the file

Comment: I'm reading a log file. The seed + number is not always the same number. Here's a larger example of the file
2022/05/13 17:32:26 10716828 118693c3 [DEBUG Client 8228] Generating level 13 area "1_1_town" with seed 3813267107
2022/05/13 17:32:28 10718437 f22b69c1 [INFO Client 8228] Tile hash: 1809335384
2022/05/13 17:32:26 10716828 118693c3 [DEBUG Client 8228] Generating level 13 area "1_1_town" with seed 1204811500

I only want to match and pull the last two digits if they are 00 to put in a variable for the larger script. I can post that script if it helps further.

Comment: If there's a match, the last 2 digits will always be `00`, so you can just set the variable to this.. And if they're not `00` there won't be a match, so there's nothing to put in the variable. I still don't get why you need to pull the digits from the line.

Comment: I need it to highlight just "00". There are other lines in the file where the number also ends in a 00. I don't want those because they aren't preceded by the keyword seed. I only want to check the number if it is on the same line as seed and the number ends in 00. If I use the regex as it is it will highlight "seed 1204811500". I need to put just the "00" in the script. I've listed the script here. It might help clarify why I only want the "00" and not the whole string.

Comment: FilePath := A_ScriptDir "\TestLogFile2.txt" ; relative path to file
File := FileOpen(FilePath, "r")
OldLogFileSize := 0
File.Seek(0, 2)

Loop
{
 LogFileSize := File.Length
 if (LogFileSize > OldLogFileSize)
 {
  Loop
  {
   if File.AtEOF
    Break
   TextLine := File.Readline()
   If InStr(TextLine, seed)
   {
    RegExMatch(TextLine, "\bseed\s+\d*00$", RFNum) 
    MsgBox, % "The ID is " RFNum
   }
  }
  OldLogFileSize := LogFileSize
 }
 Sleep, 1000 ; wait one second before checking again (change to whatever)
}
return

Esc::
 File.Close()
 ExitApp
return

Comment: How are you using this for highlighting?

Comment: You could get the start and end position of the match, then highlight the 2 characters before the end.

Comment: How do I get the start and end position and then highlight the two characters "00" in the regex expression ?

Comment: It depends on the language I don't recognize the language you're using in the comment, so I don't know how to do it there.

Comment: According to regexe101.com I'm using PCRE2 flavor if that helps

Comment: I mean the programming language: `FilePath := A ScriptDir`. Is that Pascal?

Comment: Oh sorry - no it's the syntax language used in autohotkey (autohotkey.com)

Comment: I've updated the answer to use a lookbehind.

Comment: This works great ! Thank you so much. Maybe one last thing. Is there a way to cater for a range. The number can actually be be either a 9 or a 10 digit number (so the behind look up would be 7 or 8.)

Comment: That's a problem for this solution, because lookbehinds have to be fixed-length.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Some regex flavors allow a range but not the one I'm using. This is the best answer I'll get. Thank you for your time and patience helping to solve the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

[AHK `RegExMatch`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExMatch.htm) runs on PCRE regular expression engine.

Use

```
RegExMatch(TextLine, "\bseed\s+\d*\K00$", RFNum)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/ikIvl9/1). The number matched by `\d*` can actually be any digit long. `\K` cuts off all text before the last `00`.

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  seed                     'seed'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and &quot; &quot;) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       match reset operator
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  00                       '00'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: This seems to overcome the issue of a varying number of digits. It will select the 00 if it's an 8,9 or 10 digit number. Thanks for improving the query even further.

Answer (score 0):

Since different languages handle regex differently, here is a Java based solution.  The first two ways return true if the seed is there.  The third way, captures the seed number.

The first matches any complete string that contains the requested criteria. Even though your seed was at the end of the line, this doesn't require that.

- `.*` - one or more of any character (here matches irrelevant characters)
- `seed\\s+` - seed followed by one or more white space characters
- `\\d+00`  -  one or more digits
- `(?!\\d)` - not followed by a digit

```
String s =
        "2022/05/13 17:32:26 10716828 118693c3 [DEBUG Client 8228] Generating level 13 area \"1_1_town\" with seed 120481576136500";

String regex1 = ".*seed\\s+\\d+?00(?!\\d).*";
System.out.println(s.matches(regex1));
```

prints

```
true
```

This is similar in that it returns true if it finds the pattern within the string. Thus the ending and trailing irrelevant characters (i.e. `.*`) are not needed

```
String regex2 = "seed\\s+\\d+?00(?!\\d)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex2).matcher(s);
System.out.println(m.find());
```

prints

```
true
```

If you want to retrieve the seed, do it like this by putting parens around the digits to form a capture group.

```
String regex2 = "seed\\s+(\\d+?00)(?!\\d)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex2).matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

prints

```
120481576136500
```